# select dropdown does not enable in edit page when the checkbox get auto selected in edit page

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ship_to_checkbox").change(function() {                
        var ch = this.checked;      
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#mj").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#mj').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

here is my checkbox code

```
<section>
    <input type="checkbox" class="ship_to_checkbox" 
            name="ship_to_checkbox" 
            value="Yes" {if $ship_check_result['ship_check']=="Yes"} checked="checked" : ""{/if}>
    <label style="font-weight: 400;">Ship to</label>
</section>
```

Comment: Now the code is better indented, do you see the javascript has an unnecessary `});` at the end

Comment: How to code a [`<label>`](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-label-tag.html)

Comment: I dont recognise this syntax `{if $ship_check_result['ship_check']=="Yes"} checked="checked" : ""{/if}` are you using a framework